# Spark MLLib's Word2Vec cosine similarity greater than 1

Tags: artificial-intelligence, word2vec, word-embeddings, spark-mllib

On the [spark implementation of word2vec](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/mllib-feature-extraction.html#word2vec), when the number of iterations or data partitions are greater than one, for some reason, the cosine similarity is greater than 1.

In my knowledge, cosine similarity should always be about $-1 < \cos\theta  < 1$. Does anyone know why?

Comment: Not sure about MlLib, but it happens on Scipy too. They use a different formula.  Check this [answer](http://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/8426/cosine-distance-1-in-scipy/8429#8429).  So, check out whether MlLib uses a different formula too.

Comment: Perhaps the vectors are not normalized?

Answer (score 4):

The Spark documentation for this kind of thing doesn't seem very thorough, so I looked at the source. There's a comment [here](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/8b292b19c9b3aaaa51b919a12132e099e5be832d/mllib/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/mllib/feature/Word2Vec.scala#L529) saying

```
// Need not divide with the norm of the given vector since it is constant.
```

This seems consistent with the following code.

So, it seems that `findSynonyms` doesn't actually return cosine distances, but rather cosine distances times the norm of the query vector. The ordering and relative values are consistent with the true cosine distance, but the actual values are all scaled.

Not sure why the number of iterations or data partitions should have any bearing on this.

Comment: Hi . Thanks for response. I am getting the same error and thinking why is that happening. Normalization will not have any effect on the cosine values. 

You are saying the output of spark findSynonyms is not a cosine similarity but cosine similarity*norm(input query). Here input query you mean is the word whose synonyms we are trying to find? 

If yes, then if I do w2vecmodel.transform(input_word) and then get the norm of that vector and dividing the output of findSynonmys by that it should be the cosine distance then?

Comment: @Baktaawar Yes, that seems to be the case based on my reading of the code as someone who's never used Spark, but you should run some checks yourself before relying on that.